# Get average, Sum from table 1 matching interval in table 2

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

**Situation**

- I have two tables as under.
- I want to get the average and sum of    values from table1 which
  falls in interval of table 2 (also has the    output data) where Sunnary is NULL.

**Table 1**

```
Name    Val1    Val2    Start   End Summary
xyz     6.7     5.33    0       10  test1
xyz     7.16    4.41    10      20  test2
xyz     2.52    1.69    20      30  NULL
xyz     1       1.77    30      40  NULL
xyz     4       5.28    40      50  NULL
xyz     2.7     4.91    50      60  NULL
xyz     1.72    1.88    60      70  NULL
xyz     0.98    1.64    70      80  NULL
xyz     1.28    1.26    80      90  NULL
xyz     1.51    1.29    90      100 NULL
xyz     1.62    1.69    100     110 NULL
xyz     2.49    2.89    110     120 NULL
xyz     1.2     2.11    120     130 NULL
xyz     1.45    1.27    130     140 NULL
xyz     1.62    1.61    140     150 NULL
xyz     1.96    1.68    150     160 NULL
xyz     2.03    2.48    160     170 NULL
xyz     2.42    1.72    170     180 NULL
xyz     1.64    1.47    180     190 NULL
xyz     3.08    3.36    190     200 NULL
xyz     1.45    2.41    200     210 NULL
xyz     1.86    3.23    210     220 NULL
xyz     1.25    1.96    220     230 NULL
xyz     2.68    2.64    230     240 NULL
xyz     1.99    3.92    240     250 NULL
xyz     1.76    3.35    250     260 NULL
xyz     2.94    3.86    260     270 NULL
xyz     4.1     4.15    270     278 NULL
```

**Table 2**

```
Name    Begin           End             Summary
xyz     0               100             test1/test2
xyz     100             200             NULL
xyz     200             278             NULL
```

**Table 3 (Output Table)**

```
Name    Avg(Val1)   Sum(Val1)   Avg(Val1)   Avg(Val2)       Begin           End         Summary
xyz     1.9637      15.71       2.465       19.72           0               100         test1/test2
xyz     1.951       19.51       2.028       20.28           100             200         NULL
xyz     2.25375     18.03       3.19        25.52           200             278         NULL
```

I tried the following code but it didnt work

```
select A.[Name], avg(A.Val1), sum(A.Val1), avg(A.Val2)
,sum(A.Val2), B.Start, B.End  from table1 A
left join table2 B on A.Start = B.Start and A.End = B.End
where  A.Name=B.Name
group by Name
```

Comment: That's easy. Join using the range and aggregate.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have added the code that I tried but didnt work.

Comment: the expected output that you have posted does it correspond to the sample data that you posted ?

Comment: @Squirrel yes, table3 has output that I expect from table 1 and table2. Three rows of table 3 has an average and sum of all the rows from table1 where Summary is NULL in intervals as per table2 and data from table1

Comment: @Squirrel i applied the condition Summary is Null. So it will be sum of 2.52 + 1 + 4 + 2.7 + 1.72 + 0.98 + 1.28 + 1.51 = 15.71, We need to neglect 6.7 and 7.16 as its Summary is not NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any need to use `LEFT JOIN` and all join condition between the 2 tables should be in the `ON` clause

Also you need a condition `A.Summary is null` in your where clause. (I assumed you are referring to the `Summary` in table 1)

```
select A.[Name], 
       avg(A.Val1), 
       sum(A.Val1), 
       avg(A.Val2),
       sum(A.Val2), 
       B.Start, 
       B.End  
from   table1 A
       inner join table2 B on  A.Name   = B.Name
                          and  A.Start >= B.Start 
                          and  A.End   <= B.End
where  A.Summary is null
group by A.Name, B.Start, B.End
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoudn't be joining on equal, should be >= and < or > and <=, depending on where the boundary sits. But you need one end of your table2 to go outside your actual figures, so make the last one 999 or the first one -1. And as your name is part of the join keep it consistent.

```
select A.[Name], B.Start, B.End, avg(A.Val1), sum(A.Val1), avg(A.Val2)
,sum(A.Val2), B.Start, B.End  from table1 A
left join table2 B on A.Name=B.Name and A.Start >= B.Start and A.End < B.End
group by Name, B.Start, B.End
```

Comment: that dint work for me. It averaging and summing all the values of Table 1, its not doing as per table 3. When I run above query it averages and sums all val1 and val2 from Start 0 to End 278 and returns one row. I am expecting 3 rows like table3

Comment: Sorry - group by should include the table 2 values. I'll fix.

Comment: Sorry @TomC its still returning single row with incorrect data.

Comment: @duffer - this is what happens when you take the OP query and just try and edit it :( Yes it should be a inner join. And the check for null summary also. Dont know why this would be getting a single row though.